# How to mutiply arrays of matrices in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

```
from numpy import *

a = ones((2,3,N))
b = ones((3,2,N))
```

I want to matrix multiply b*a for each of the N matrices. I could do this

```
c = zeros((3,3,N))
for i in range(N):
    c[:,:,i] = b[:,:,i].dot(a[:,:,i])
```

but it's slow for large N. Is there a fast way to do this in one line?

Comment: `@`/`matmul` is designed to handle `N` batches of `dot` products - but that `N` is has to be the first dimension, not the last.

Comment: I think you mean  `c[:,:,i] = b[:,:,i].dot(a[:,:,i])` in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just swap the axes around a bit so that N is the first dimension, and then you can multiply them straight. I'm also swapping c back to your desired shape of 3x3xN:

```
N = 10
a = np.ones((2,3,N))
b = np.ones((3,2,N))
a = a.swapaxes(1,2).swapaxes(0,1)
b = b.swapaxes(1,2).swapaxes(0,1)
c = (b@a).swapaxes(0,1).swapaxes(1,2)
print(c.shape)
>>> (3, 3, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is `transpose`:

```
N = 5

c = (b.transpose(2,0,1) @ a.transpose(2,0,1)).transpose(1,2,0)

c.shape
# (3,3,5)
```